# How to apply Eisenstein's criterion in complex polynomial

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

I have two questions

First,

If $f(x) = x + i$, how can I apply Eisenstein's criterion to prove that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}[x]$?

Second,

For $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^3$, $f(x,y)$ is irreducible over ($\mathbb{C}[y])[x]$, in which $f(x,y) = x^2 + (-jy)(jy^2)$. Is it correct?

Comment: Why do you want to apply Eisenstein to the trivial case $f(x)=x+i$? By definition it is irreducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An univariate polynomial over an algebraically closed field is irreducible if and only if its degree is one. So $x+i$ is certainly irreducible. For $x^2+y^3$, this polynomial is irreducible in $(\mathbb C(y))[x]$, since it is a quadric without a root over a field.

Comment: Does a quadric without a root over $ \mathbb{C}[y]$ means $(-jy^2)$?

Comment: What do you mean by $j$? A root of $f(x)=x^2-y^3$ would be $\pm \sqrt{y^3}$, which is not an element in $\mathbb{C}[y]$, since it is not a polynomial (or a rational function) in $y$.

Comment: Hence for $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$, its root in $\mathbb{C}[y]$ is $ ± \sqrt{y^2}$ which an element in $ \mathbb{C}[y]$?
Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, $x^2+y^2=(x+iy)(x-iy)$.